# optional expressions in Irony

Tags: c#, grammar, irony

I'm new in Irony programming. 
the first test example that I'm working on is to calculate mathematical shapes (Area, Volume ,...)

in simple mode, it is working fine. but the challenge is that I want to make it optional. For example, if I choose circle as shape then I only need radius. plus, if I choose rectangle as shape I need height and width. So, I want to know how to get one number as radius when shape is circle and how to get 2 or 3 numbers when shape is rectangle.

```
            var program = new NonTerminal("program");
            var shapeType = new NonTerminal("shapeType");
            var shapeTypes = new NonTerminal("shapeTypes");
            var circle = new NonTerminal("circle");
            var square = new NonTerminal("square");
            var rectangle = new NonTerminal("rectangle");
            var triangle = new NonTerminal("triangle");
            var commandList = new NonTerminal("commandList");
            var command = new NonTerminal("command");
            var width = new NonTerminal("width");
            var height = new NonTerminal("height");
            var length = new NonTerminal("length");
            var radius = new NonTerminal("radius");
            var number = new NumberLiteral("number");
            var operation = new NonTerminal("operation");

            this.Root = program;

            program.Rule = shapeType + radius + commandList |
                shapeType + length + commandList |
                shapeType + width + commandList |
                shapeType + length + width + commandList |
                shapeType + height + commandList |
            shapeType + length + width + height + commandList;
            shapeType.Rule = Symbol("set") + "shape" + ":" + shapeTypes + ".";
            shapeTypes.Rule = Symbol("circle") | "square" | "rectangle" | "triangle";
            radius.Rule = Symbol("set") + "radius" + ":" + number + ".";
            height.Rule = Symbol("set") + "height" + ":" + number + ".";
            width.Rule = Symbol("set") + "width" + ":" + number + ".";
            length.Rule = Symbol("set") + "length" + ":" + number + ".";

            triangle.Rule = height + width | height + width + length;
            rectangle.Rule = height + width | height + width + length;
            square.Rule = height + width | height + width + length;
            circle.Rule = radius;
            operation.Rule = Symbol("area") | "volume";
            commandList.Rule = MakeStarRule(commandList, null, command);
            command.Rule = Symbol("what") + "is" + operation + ".";
```

It behaves like this:
for circle shape example, I want my code to receive only radius and no more (like the code below - listing 1). but, it can work also when the syntax is like the listing 2. so, I want specific circumstances in compilation.

**Listing 1**

```
set shape : circle.
set radius : 10.
what is area.
```

**Listing 2**

```
set shape : circle.
set length : 10.
set width : 5.
what is area.
```

they both result the same answer which we know that the Listing 2 parameters are wrong.

Comment: Is there anyone who knows Irony...

Comment: Could you be more specific? Ideally, add an example of your code, explain how it behaves and how do you want it to behave.

Comment: @svick I added the sample code that I'm working on. could you please help me to solve this. Do you have any good source **Book or something** that instructs Irony ?

Comment: Wild guess here ... does this Irony language have if statements? If so, try using those!

Comment: @hatcyl as far as I have know about it, no it doesn't have If statement. and so you should know it's not a programming language, it is a grammar language

Comment: What is the purpose of the `trinagle`, `rectangle`, `square` and `circle` nonterminals? They don't seem to be used anywhere.

Comment: @svick not at the moment but they will be used later. do you know how to resolve my issue. and by the way, do you know any reference ?

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you're trying to do, however, such "conditional" behavior is not done using grammars - this will make grammars harder to understand, and hell to maintance, plus it's not that easy too.

Instead, you will have what you have. After you pass in input string to Irony, it will give you back a "parse tree": [How to Generate and display ParseTree for an expression in C# using Irony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944857/how-to-generate-and-display-parsetree-for-an-expression-in-c-sharp-using-irony)

The parse tree can also be further transformed into AST(abstract synax tree), Irony has samples on that too.

Once you have parse tree/AST, you will have to do simple analysis over tokens, and flag all the inappropriate behavior.

By analysis, I mean, iterate over the tokens, keep some kind of "context information".

Essentially, the logic will look like this:

```
if set shape was set to circle:
  if set length exists
     return true; // nothing wrong here, we can calculate area.
  if set length exists and set width exists
     return true;

  return false; // error: we can't decide it..
```

Hope it helps. Irony has also simple examples how to build an actual programming language with interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

To make a rule optional, [use the `Q()` method on it](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Irony_-_Language_Implementation_Kit/Grammar/Non_Terminals#Kleene_Operators).

Comment: could you be more specific. I couldn't understand what Q() method is for.